# MongoDB - Issue with Aggregate function matching Reference Data into separate Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In the example here - https://mongoplayground.net/p/gxg-ZFKhv0B,
Is there a way to return only REF_123 , as we are returning only its parent OF_Code, Can it be achieved ? I see both REF_123 and REF_456 are returned as the lookup is happening before the facet is being called.

I’m new at this, Does anyone have any idea?

**document1 - "ParentDocument":**

```
[
{
"code": "OF_Code",
"version": "1",
"createdBy": "abc",
 "attributes": {
"associatedProducts": [
  {
    "bundleProducts": [
      {
        "products": [
          {
            "key": "REF_123"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
},
{
"code": "OF_Code2",
"version": "1",
"createdBy": "abc",
"attributes": {
"associatedProducts": [
  {
    "bundleProducts": [
      {
        "products": [
          {
            "key": "REF_123"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
},
{
"code": "OF_Code3",
"version": "1",
"createdBy": "abc",
"attributes": {
"associatedProducts": [
  {
    "bundleProducts": [
      {
        "products": [
          {
            "key": "REF_456"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
  }
 ]
```

**document2- "ReferencedDocument":**

```
[
{
"code": "REF_123",
"status": "live"
},
{
 "code": "REF_456",
"status": "live"
},
{
"code": "REF_789",
"status": "live"
}
]
```

**Query -**

```
db.parents.aggregate([
{
"$match": {
  "code": {
    "$in": [
      "OF_Code",
      "OF_Code2",
      "OF_Code3"
    ]
  }
  }
  },
  {
 "$lookup": {
  "from": "reference",
  "localField": 
 "attributes.associatedProducts.bundleProducts.products.key",
  "foreignField": "code",
  "as": "refs",
  "pipeline": [
    {
      "$project": {
        "_id": 0
      }
    }
  ]
  }
},
{"$facet": {
"pagination": [
  {
    "$count": "count"
  }
],
"Parent": [
  {
    "$skip": 0
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  }
],
"Reference": [
  {
    "$unwind": "$refs"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "Reference": {
        "$addToSet": "$refs"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$Reference"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$Reference"
  }
]
}
},
{
"$unset": "_id"
},
{
"$unset": "Parent.refs"
}
])
```

**Currently Both the Reference are returned**

```
"Reference": [
  {
    "code": "REF_123",
    "status": "live"
  },
  {
    "code": "REF_456",
    "status": "live"
  }
]
```

**Need only REF_123 as OF_Code is only referencing REF_123**

```
"Reference": [
  {
    "code": "REF_123",
    "status": "live"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question.  Links to mongoplayground.net are nice because they help people reproduce the issue, but this question won't be much use to future visitors once the playground drops the code.

Comment: @joe Updated the code in the question